# Java bind exception when trying to use rvm jruby

Tags: java, rvm, jruby

I'm really confused by this error. I'm not sure what the process is using Java. Doing `kill -9 <pid>` doesn't help either. I've tried reinstalling jruby. I'm stumped.

```
[phoenix (master)]$ rvm use jruby
Using /Users/jess/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0
[phoenix (master)]$ java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:382)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
    at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGServer.run(NGServer.java:411)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[phoenix (master)]$ ps aux | grep java
jess             1197   0.0  0.4  4391504  29456 s000  S     2:01PM   0:00.95 /usr/bin/java -Xmx500m -Xss2048k -Djffi.boot.library.path=/Users/jess/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/jni -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/jess/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/jruby.jar:/Users/jess/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/jruby-truffle.jar:/Users/jess/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/jruby-truffle.jar: -Djruby.home=/Users/jess/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.0.0.0 -Djruby.lib=/Users/jess/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib -Djruby.script=jruby -Djruby.shell=/bin/sh org.jruby.main.NailServerMain
jess             5365   0.0  0.0  2432772    648 s000  S+    2:15PM   0:00.00 grep java
```

I also get this error quite frequently, after killing processes associated with java and jruby.

```
error: ng executable not found; run 'make' in /Users/jess/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.0.0.0/tool/nailgun
```

UPDATE

Do I need to change this file; and if so, how?

```
[phoenix (master)]$ cat ~/.rvm/hooks/after_use_jruby
#!/usr/bin/env bash

\. "${rvm_path}/scripts/functions/hooks/jruby"

if [[ "${rvm_ruby_string}" =~ "jruby" ]]
then
  jruby_ngserver_start
  jruby_options_append "--ng" "${PROJECT_JRUBY_OPTS[@]}"
else
  jruby_options_remove "--ng" "${PROJECT_JRUBY_OPTS[@]}"
  jruby_clean_project_options
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, JRuby is of course using Java since it is a Ruby implementation of Ruby.

In your case it seems that you are starting JRuby with [Nailgun](http://martiansoftware.com/nailgun/) enabled. Nailgun is a Ruby wrapper around Java which speeds up the start of the Java JVM - see also https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Improving-startup-time. Nailgun starts a server which listens per default on port 2113. My guess is that that's where the problem lies. Maybe another process is using this port?

RVM actually does try to start the Nailgun server automatically after `rvm use jruby`. See `~/.rvm/hooks/after_use_jruby`. You can remove or change this script to avoid the use of Nailgun.

Comment: `[phoenix (master)]$ lsof -i:2113
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    9439 jess   17u  IPv6 0x99bbb8b0eec4fe77      0t0  TCP *:hsl-storm (LISTEN)`

Comment: they have the same PID

Comment: I commented the `after_use_jruby` file and killed the java process and the same behavior persists. Thank you so much for helping.